# How to default to Week view in Outlook 2007 Calendar?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007, calendar

Whenever I open my Calendar, I find myself in Month view. But I prefer the Week view. If I move away and then back to Calendar, I'm right back in Month again.

How can I make Week view "stick" so it starts out there when I enter the Calendar?

Answer (score 0):

It should stick.  If it doesn't, open Outlook with the command line parameter `/clearviews` (you can add the `/clearviews` to the end of the "target" line in the shortcut).

That should reset the view behavior to the default.  Remove that command line parameter once you open outlook, though, as you don't want to do it every time.

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The parameter is actually /cleanviews

Sadly, didn't help. I suspect some add-on is causing mischief.